# How to use setBlockedUrsl with selenium firefox driver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently I created a program that blocked some requests in the selenium chrome driver via dev tools using the code bellow

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setBlockedURLs', {"urls": ["someurl.com"]})
                driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
```

It works fine however when trying to use the same code with firefox driver I got the following error

```
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'executed_cdp_cmd'
```

So, how to do the same with firefox driver?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this, as I would also like to know how to do this in FireFox?